# Is my solution to a geometry problem correct?

Tags: geometry

[image]

This problem can be solved using the sine law on triangles ΑΒΔ & ΑΔΓ. But i thought about what was given, that $ΔΓ/ΔΒ=\sqrt3$ and i did what you see here. My concern is, am i allowed to do such a thing an jump into the conclusion that since $\tan(45^\circ)\cot(30^\circ)=\sqrt3$ as was given then the two triangles must be right triangles. This is my question, whether what i did was logically and mathematically correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have very neat handwriting.

Comment: I think you have already assumed that they are right triangles before showing it. Because, it seems that you have taken $\Delta \Gamma/ A\Delta=\tan 45$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll denote $\Delta=D$ and $\Gamma=C$ .

From the law of sines :

$$\frac{BD}{\sin 30^{\circ}}=\frac{AD}{\sin B}$$
$$\frac{CD}{\sin 45^{\circ}}=\frac{AD}{\sin C}$$

Now dividing them and using the known values for the sines :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{\sin C}{\sin B}$$

It's also easy to see that $B+C=105^{\circ}$

Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(105^{\circ}-x)}{\sin x}$$

We want the angle $B$ such that $$f(B)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

You noticed that it will work if those angles are right , that is for $B=60^{\circ}$ .

Now I'll prove that $f$ is one-to-one on the interval $(0^{\circ},105^{\circ})$  .

Assume that $f(x)=f(y)$ . This means that :

$$\sin x \sin (105^{\circ}-y)=\sin y \sin (105^{\circ}-x)$$

Now transform the products into differences :

$$\frac{1}{2}(\cos(105^{\circ}-x-y)-\cos (105^{\circ}-y+x))=\frac{1}{2} (\cos (105^{\circ}-x-y)-\cos (
105^{\circ}-x+y))$$
After simplifications :
$$\cos (105^{\circ}-y+x)=\cos(105^{\circ}-x+y)$$

This means either their sum or difference is a multiple of $2\pi$ .

- If their sum is :
  $$210^{\circ}=2k\pi$$ which is false .
- If their difference is :
  $$2x-2y=2k\pi$$
  $$x-y=k \pi$$ but because $x$ and $y$ are in the interval $(0^{\circ},105^{\circ})$ we must have $x-y=0^{\circ}$  or $x=y$ .

This means that $f$ is an one-to-one function :

So because $B=60^{\circ} $ works it follows that :

$$f(B)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=f(60^{\circ})$$ 
$$B=60^{\circ}$$ which is thus the only solution .

Now to answer your question :

You can't be sure that there aren't more solutions than the one you found so you can't assume it's the only one from the start .If you think it's indeed the only solution you must prove that is , or else your argument isn't convincing .

Answer (score 2):

The information that is given by the question is not enough. The right angle case (that is assumed)is a possible solution. However, it is not unique.

Comment: You are right. I was confused. I see that others pointed out also. I ASSUMED first that the triangle was right triangle and then i showed it. duh. Thanks!